# Act On Somebody

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

When I was reading a text, I encountered a sentence which contains the verb phrase "act on".

> The Internet and smartphone applications are used for distributing hate messages and acting on the users of them.

My Turkish-English dictionary says that the meaning of this verb is to influence.

On the other hand, when I search it on the website [www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/act-on?q=act%20on), I see that this verb can only be used with things, not people. It is defined as act on/upon something,

Can this verb phrase have the meaning of influencing someone?

Can it be used with anyone?

Comment: I agree with the Oxford Dictionary: act on can only be used for things. The sentence as it stands does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Question one: yes.  Question two: yes.

*Act on* has three meanings:

1. to do something because you have been advised or told to do it
2. to use (something, such as a feeling or suggestion) as a reason or basis for doing something
3. to make something happen : to have a particular effect

See the Cambridge Dictionary and the Merriam-Webster Dictionary

Fake news acts on my nerves like kids scraping their fingernails across a blackboard.          (1)

Hateful tweets are something that Twitter should act on.      (3)

Hate messages act on people in a very direct and damaging way.  (3)

Comment: M-W only lists Def 2: _to use (something, such as a feeling or suggestion) as a reason or basis for doing something_. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/act-on-sth) says: _to do something because you have been advised or told to do it:_ Your meaning 3 here is meaning 6 in [M-W](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/act), but that's for _act_, not for _act on_, and the example sentence is: _These medications act on the heart_. Both the OP's original and your sample seem awkward. Note, too, that typing `"messages act on people"` into Google yields zero hits.